# Visual Studio Published Project Crashing when trying to access Database files

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This is the biggest problem I've had with my project so far. Every time I try to publish it, I get hangups and crashes whenever the project tries to access a database file (which is fairly often).

I have two database objects, both created as part of my Visual Studio project under the main solution, as BUILDERDATA.mdf and CHARACTERS.mdf. When I access them during test builds, everything functions just fine. However, they always fail in the published project.

I get the feeling either they're not exporting correctly, or the act of publishing the project is breaking the connection strings, so I'm hoping someone can help me pinpoint the issue.

Under my project settings, I have a connection set up to each database. They're both Connection Strings, their scope is Application, and the value is this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BUILDERDATA.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CHARACTERS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Under Project Properties -> Publish -> Application Files, both databases and their log files are set to Data File (Auto) for Publish Status, Required for Download Group, and Include for Hash.

Under my Prerequisites, I have SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB marked, as well as Microsoft .NET Framework 4. Part of my code uses .NET, so that's required anyway, and I included SQL Server Express so it can access the database files. However, 2012 is the newest version available for me to include, so I'm not sure if there's an issue with that version?

If there's anything else you guys would need to see, please let me know. I just want to get this figured out and fixed so I can have my friends start testing my program. :(

Comment: Posting the error message you get be a huge help.

Comment: The basic message just says that an "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.", and "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.", yadda yadda yadda, "error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist."

There's the "Detailed" error also, which is HUUUGE, so I don't just want to post it here.

Comment: Can you verify that those 2 `mdf` files actually exist on the machine you are publishing to?  The error is pretty clear that the problem is that it can't find those databases.  Now we need to investigate why it can't find them.

Comment: I actually have no idea where my program installed to. :p So, let me dig around for a little bit, and I'll see if the databases are in the directory. That's actually something I never even considered, if they were actually there at all.

Comment: Ok, I think I maybe found where the program installed to? I'm not completely sure though, because all of the files in the directory are appended with a ".deploy" after the file extension. I don't think that's normal, it seems more like those were the files used during installation. In that case, both of the database files are there, just, as I said, with a ".deploy" after the extension. I'll do a little more digging and see if I can find the files somewhere else. EDIT: Confirmed, that's where the files were installed to. So, all of my live files are appended oddly. Maybe that's part of it?

Comment: Aha, that WAS NOT the installation directory after all! I was able to find it all (with proper extensions) in my AppData folder. And, oddly enough, the databases were missing from the folder there, even though they exist in my deployment files. Do you know what would cause that??

Comment: Are the mdf files included as part of the project?  Worst case, you just have to manually copy the files to the server, but it would be nice to have them deploy automatically.

Comment: As I said, the mdf files appear to be in with the installer files for the application. However, they still have that ".deploy" extension on them. I did try removing it and putting them in the proper directory, but I was still getting the crashes. I think maybe the ".deploy" extension means it was packaged a specific way, and the installer has to kind of "unencrypt" them, but I don't know how to force that. And I also don't know why the mdf files, while in the installer, aren't actually being deployed to the proper directory.